# Why do i get an error when trying to add an id to a span element in InnerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

My website crashes at this code with this error... Why?

```
      TextElement.innerHTML = "<span id="ID"> text </span>"
```

> Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

If I remove the ID, it works fine...

```
      TextElement.innerHTML = "<span> text </span>"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hint: Look at the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `"<span id="ID"> text </span>"`, it will be interpreted like this:

```
string: "<span id="
and code: ID
and string: "> text </span>"
```

Now, obviously that does not make any sense. The sentence is not terminated properly and the `ID` is not a valid JavaScript code.

You need to open and end your string properly. To do that, you have several options:

1- HTML and JavaScript can both accept single or double quotes for string values. You can make use of this fact by using different quotes inside your string, so you can either use single quotes inside double quotes or vice versa. The two lines below are equivalent:

```
TextElement.innerHTML = "<span id='ID'> text </span>";
TextElement.innerHTML = '<span id="ID"> text </span>';
```

2- This is not recommended, but HTML does not require quotes surrounding values that don't have space in them, so you can use:

```
TextElement.innerHTML = "<span id=ID> text </span>"; //NOT RECOMMENDED
```

3- You can escape the quotes in JavaScript by using the escape character `\`:

```
TextElement.innerHTML = "<span id=\"ID\"> text </span>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use single quotes inside of the double quotes. You're escaping the quote when you use the double around ID

```
TextElement.innerHTML = "<span id='ID'/> text </span>"
```